# Trying to put a list of ids with a common phrase into an array/list in selenium java

Tags: java, list, selenium, css-selectors

I need to get the IDs present in the DOM that start with "starx-" into an array. After that hyphen, there is usually some combination of uppercase, lowercase, and digits - it depends upon the dropdown selected previously. But starx- is common to all ids, no matter what is selected in the previous dropdown (and there are a LOT of options so... no to creating a bunch of "if" statements based on the previous drop down)

To do so, I created this line here to match all of the id's in the DOM that start with starx-:

`List<WebElement> allStarX = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^='starx-']"));`

So it's good at finding them. A few print statements I threw in there show me that if there are 4 such IDs in the DOM, it will find them all. If there are 7, it will have 7 elements in that List. Unfortunately , this List doesn't contain the actual IDs. It contains:

**[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WIN8_1 (f665490daee44e1039265763f67008cc)] -> css selector: [id^='starx-']]**

for each id beginning with starx- that exists in the DOM. Ideally I'd get all the ID using the .getAttribute method, but that's for strings. For example, if I add it onto the end of this:

`List<WebElement> allStarX = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^='starx-']")).getAttribute();`

I have a type mismatch. And if I do this:

```
for (WebElement starx : allStarX)
{
    starx.getAttribute("id");
    System.out.println(starx);
               
}
```

It still prints out a bunch of this:

**[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WIN8_1 (f665490daee44e1039265763f67008cc)] -> css selector: [id^='starx-']]**

I kind of know why that last one doesn't work, but I don't understand why the first one doesn't.

Absolute xpaths don't seem to work because there are a lot of previous options add and remove things from the DOM.

Can anyone suggest something that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my understanding goes, you are trying to get the IDs which start with the text of 'starx-'. You have created a list of webelements (`List<WebElement>`) and while extracting the text, you are looping it by not extracting the attribute of the id, which is the issue.

You can handle it as mentioned below:

```
List<WebElement> allStarX = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^='starx-']"));

for (WebElement starx : allStarX)
{
    System.out.println(starx.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! So now what I did instead of  `System.out.println(starx.getAttribute("id"));` was to initialize a new ArrayList called starxx and `starxx.add(starx.getAttribute("id"))` which gives me the array of id names like I wanted. Thank you so much!!!